Wordpress - Connect login of main and subdomain with two separate wordpress instances?
Currently I'm in the process to built a databank for a client which should get data on a daily/weekly basis via FTP and will place that info on the frontend avaiable for paying customers as well.
Since right now the wordpress of the main page is already quite loaded with plugins/tools/addons and loads of posts (they are a huge news magazin) the client was thinking of putting the whole databank part on a subdomain with a separate wordpress.
So we would have main-page.com for everything regarding paywall system, blog, etc. and we would have sub.main-page.com for everything regarding databank topics.
My question is: Would it be possible to connect the two wordpress instances somehow so that:

when a user logs in/out or registers on the main-page.com they would also log in/out or register on the sub.main-page.com?
when a user logs in/out or registers on the sub.main-page.com they would also log in/out or register on the main-page.com?

Would that even make sense or should we just upgrade the server to the max and leave everything on the same wordpress? (Im fearing that since we already have so much going on there, this would lead to performance problems or similar)
I was trying to look for solutions for simultanious logins on two separate wordpresses but I couldnt find much here...

I also had a similar question and found a a plugin that lets you sync users across main and subdomain sites, called "WP Remote User Sync". It works by synchronising the users on your main site and your subdomain, by user role, and it is direction specific, so you can set it to when a user registers/logs in/out on the main site, they also do that on the subdomain. I tested it and it was a bit confusing to get it to start working, but I figured it out and posted a guide here where I answered my own question, I think it would be helpful to you.
